# PHP: Write form data to text file in addition to email?

Tags: php, forms

I am using the following code to email the results of a form submission. Since I'm running without a database I'd like some sort of other record.

```
<?php
    $to = "me@me.com"; 
    $from = $_REQUEST['email']; 
    $name = $_REQUEST['name']; 
    $headers = "From: $from"; 
    $subject = "New Message"; 
    $fields = array(); 
    $fields{"first_name"} = "first_name";
    $fields{"last_name"} = "last_name"; 
    $fields{"email"} = "email"; 
    $fields{"phone"} = "phone"; 
    $fields{"hospital"} = "hospital"; 
    $fields{"title"} = "title"; 
    $body = "Here is what was sent:\n\n"; 
    foreach($fields as $a => $b){   
        $body .= sprintf("%20s: %s\n",$b,$_REQUEST[$a]); 
    }
    $send = mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);
?>
```

How do I save the results to a text file in addition to email? I've seen examples on how to do text but not in addition to email.

Comment: If you seen examples on how to write to a text file, just add it under your mail code.

Comment: I was hoping there would be a more efficient way to to do it than rewriting entire code

Comment: you don't have to rewrite it, just add the writing to file code under mail. Won't take more than just a few lines.

Answer (score 0):

you should check the file functions :

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.fread.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php

An example of what you could do :

```
$filePath = 'records.txt';
file_put_contents($filePath, "\nYour text here...", FILE_APPEND);
```

Comment: Thanks Max. Those links are French though. 
I've tried implementing your code, it writes a file but it contains no content. Do I put my variables in "\nYour text here..." ?

Comment: It depends what you want to save in the file, you should build a string with the variables you want and pass it to the function

Comment: I want to use the same string as for the email

Answer (score 0):

Should be something like this:

```
//Email code here...

if(!$file = fopen('records.txt', 'a+')) {
    echo 'Could not write to file.';
    exit;
}

$content = "Email sent on: " . time() . PHP_EOL . "***" . PHP_EOL . $body . PHP_EOL . "***" . PHP_EOL;

if(fwrite($file, $content) === false) {
    echo 'Could not write to file.';
    exit;
}

fclose($file);
```

For more see examples at: http://php.net/fwrite